# Is there a TypeScript `Partial<any>` type for a function parameter to accept `any` but be `void`?

Tags: typescript, types

For an interface, one can use `Partial<X>`, the [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types) to say "Permit all properties of X, but expect none of them".

So that the following causes a compiler error:

```
interface X { foo: boolean }

function doSomething(x: Partial<X>) {
  let aBoolean: boolean = x.foo; // ERROR: possibly undefined
}

doSomething({ foo: true }); // OK
doSomething({}); // OK
doSomething(true); // ERROR: Type 'boolean' has no properties in common with 'Partial<X>'
```

I would like to do the same thing with `any` to say "this function may accept anything as a parameter, but you can't count on anything being there"

```
function doSomething(x: Partial<any>) {
  let aBoolean: boolean = x.foo; // OK, but I wish it wasn't
}

doSomething({ foo: true }); // OK
doSomething({}); // OK
doSomething(true); // OK
doSomething(/* etc. */); // OK
```

I would like my function to accept anything and everything as an argument, but inside the function I should not be able to access any properties on the object without checking for them first. It's even ok if inside the function `x` has type `void` or `never`.

I'm not surprised `Partial<any>` doesn't work like I wish - I am definitely *not* asking "why doesn't `Partial<any>` work the way I wish it did". I'm asking:

**What type can I use for the parameter `x` such that:**

1. it accepts arguments of any/every type
2. inside the function the type of `x` is something where every property is possibly undefined (or `x` is of type `void`, etc.)

Comment: Just make `x` optional? [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20act%20%3D%20(x%3F%3A%20Partial%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20!!x.foo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aact(%7B%20foo%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0Aact(%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0Aact(true)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0Aact(%2F*%20etc.%20*%2F)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK)

Comment: There's no error when you do `!!x.foo` in that example - or if you change it to `{ let bar: string = x.foo; }`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The point was that within the function there is no guarantee what properties `x` has, and I would like the type to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What type can I use for the parameter x such that:
>
> ```
> 1. it accepts arguments of any/every type
> 2. inside the function the type of x is something where every property 
>    is possibly undefined (or x is of type void, etc.)
> ```

It's empty object type `{}`, which is compatible with almost any type and allows you to pass almost anything to `doSomething`:

```
function doSomething(x?: {})  {...}

doSomething({ foo: true }); // OK
doSomething({}); // OK
doSomething(true); // OK
doSomething(/* etc. */); // OK
```

But nothing is known about it in the implementation, and you can't use it without checking first:

```
function doSomething(x?: {})  {
    //let b: boolean = x; // error
    //let o: {} = x; // error when strictNullChecks in on
    //let bar: string = x.foo;  // error

    if (typeof x === 'boolean') {
        let b: boolean = x;
    }
    if (x !== undefined) {
        if (hasProperty(ofTypeString, x, 'foo')) {
            let bar: string = x.foo;
        }
    }
};

function hasProperty<T, N extends string>(
    guard: (p: any) => p is T, 
    x: {}, 
    name: N
): x is {[n in N]: T} 
{
    return (name in x) && guard((x as any)[name]);
}


function ofTypeString(p: any): p is string {
    return typeof p === 'string'
}
```